# CSS hack not working anymore

Tags: css

I used some CSS hacks in my code and I changed it but now it does not work anymore.

Here is the example

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    h1:before {
    top: 102px;
}}
```

before I used this code (that worked):

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
div#hr-title {
    top: 102px;
}}
```

I dont understand. why does it not work anymore? Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure to include the [`content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content) property when using the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.

Comment: @Adrift Also, you would need positioning in order for `top` to work.. `absolute`, `relative` etc.. `content:"\A"` would work.

Comment: You really need to make it clear why do you need CSS that only works in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you're trying to use a [Gecko-specific (as in Mozilla Firefox) CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F%40document#Browser_compatibility).  There's no reason it shouldn't work in Firefox, and without any further context or example we can only take wild guesses as to why it doesn't work in your setup.  Are you trying to use it in a non-Firefox browser?

You may also want to re-evaluate this hack and try to write your CSS such that you don't need to target specific browsers with disparate styles.